# Not able to compile: android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin. Please use 'annotationProcessor' configuration instead

Tags: java, android

I am getting following error on compiling. I couldn't find a working solution from the google search. I would really appreciate if someone could help me to figure out.

---

```
ERROR: android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin.  
Please use 'annotationProcessor' configuration instead.
Affected Modules: app
```

```
ERROR: Failed to parse XML in /Users/SPEED/Documents/Projects/Move/V2/MoveIt/Android Source Code/pick_Pasengger/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
ParseError at [row,col]:[201,13]
Message: expected start or end tag
Affected Modules: app
```

I Have updated all com.android.support: to the same version 27.1.1

```
enter code here 
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:volley-integration:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'



    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.1.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
```

Comment: `classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'` - what happens if you remove this line?

Comment: Getting following error

org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-measurement-connector-impl/17.0.5/firebase-measurement-connector-impl-17.0.5-javadoc.jar'

org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.getFailed(ResourceExceptions.j
 -----
 ------
 -------
ggingExternalResource.openStream(ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.java:62)
 at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.AccessorBackedExternalResource.withContentIfPresent(AccessorBackedExternalResource.java:135)
 ... 140 more